# Mysql import from script

Tags: python, mysql

I am using csv parsing for import csv files in my sql. I have few tables in Mysql. I wnat to import csv file in all table once. so i have use the below script. In that country is able to import but state table did not it show me the following error

```
csv_spliter.py:74: Warning: Incorrect integer value: ''country_id'' for column 'id' at row 1
  row)
csv_spliter.py:74: Warning: Incorrect integer value: ''0'' for column 'id' at row 1
  row)
csv_spliter.py:74: Warning: Incorrect integer value: ''1'' for column 'id' at row 1
  row)
csv_spliter.py:74: Warning: Incorrect integer value: ''2'' for column 'id' at row 1
  row)
csv_spliter.py:74: Warning: Incorrect integer value: ''3'' for column 'id' at row 1
  row)
Done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_spliter.py", line 89, in <module>
    row)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lcm`.`state`, CONSTRAINT `state_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)')
you@you-desktop:~/Desktop$ 


      <i>      

      # initialize with empty ints and dicts
        name,cities,countries,states=[],[],[],[]

        with open('ind.csv','rb') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            reader.next() #skip header
            for row in reader:
                name.append(row[0])
                cities.append(row[2])
                states.append(row[3])
                countries.append(row[4])
        cl = list(set(countries))
        sl = list(set(states))
        citl = list(set(cities))
        inf1 = list(set(name)) 



        with open('countries.csv','w') as cfile:
            writer = csv.writer(cfile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(['country_id','name'])
            for i,x in enumerate(cl):
                writer.writerow([i,x])

        with open('state.csv','w') as cfile:
            writer = csv.writer(cfile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(['state_id','country_id','state'])
            for i,x in enumerate(sl):
                writer.writerow([i,x,cl.index(countries[states.index(x)])])

        with open('cities.csv','w') as cfile:
            writer = csv.writer(cfile,delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(['city_id','city','st_id','country_id'])
            for i,x in enumerate(citl):
                writer.writerow([i,x,sl.index(states[cities.index(x)]),
                                 cl.index(countries[cities.index(x)])
                                 ])


        with open('inf123.csv','w') as cfile:
            writer = csv.writer(cfile,delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(['Name_id', 'Name','city_id','st_id','country_id'])
            for i,x in enumerate(inf1):
                writer.writerow([i,x,
                                citl.index(cities[name.index(x)]),
                                sl.index(states[name.index(x)]),
                                cl.index(countries[name.index(x)])

                                 ])

        import MySQLdb 
        import csv
        mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # The Host 
        user="root", # username 
        passwd="root", # password 
        db="abcm") # name of the data base


        cursor = mydb.cursor()

        csv_data = csv.reader(file('countries.csv'))
        for row in csv_data:

            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO country(id, \
                  name )' \
                  'VALUES("%s", "%s")', 
                  row)
        #close the connection to the database.
        mydb.commit()
        cursor.close()
        print "Done"


        cursor = mydb.cursor()

        csv_data = csv.reader(file('state.csv'))
        for row in csv_data:

            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO state(id, \
                  country, name )' \
                  'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', 
                  row)
        #close the connection to the database.
        mydb.commit()
        cursor.close()
        print "Done"
        </i>
```

Can any one give me some advice how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting your strings to integers before dumping them in the database?

I think that's where the `Incorrect integer value` error messages are coming from.